# How are these magnetic items working?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Recently, I realized the following: I have three magnetic items, very common things to attach to your fridge to stick some notes to it and the like. Let's label them with A, B and C.

- A and B stick together
- B and C stick together
- A and C do not stick together
- but all can be attached to the fridge.

Why is that?

Comment: Just a question , by saying that A and C don't stick together , does it imply that they repel each other ?

Comment: @AarushiAgarwal Yes, indeed, they do.

Comment: I don't think it would matter which poles are attracted to the refrigerator, the fridge magnets will temporarily induce magnetism in the refrigerator and therefore get attracted to it .

Comment: Fridge magnets are often magnetized in a stripe pattern. If the width of the stripes of A and C don't match well, then they may not stick together.

Answer (score 1):

You realize that magnets have two poles called N and S
so your fridge magnets have poles on one side, the other is covered up with some material. so A has its N to the fridge, B his S and C its N
so S and N attract each other N and N and S and S repeal each other, so if you turn around your C it may be a little attracted bei A since too much is in between maybe not very much. All poles are attracted by iron.